# Monitor resolution leaves a blank spot

Tags: resolution

When I set my monitor resolution to 1152x864, the desktop moves to right and it leaves a blank spot on the right. What could be causing this?  On another resolution it is okay, but on 1152x864 it moves to the right.  How can I fix this?  I cant give image because when I take a screen shot the problem doesn't appear on the image.  It captures only the desktop and the blank spot is not a part of the desktop.  Any ideas on how to move the desktop to the right on that resolution?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your monitor might not support 1152x864, it is not a very common resolution.  It might go into "panning mode" where the screen follows the mouse around a larger virtual screen, or display the desktop on part of your monitor, depending on your video card and monitor settings.  You should try to determine the native resolution of your monitor and test it at that setting.

If this does not seem to be related to what is going on, a picture with a digital camera or cell phone would probably help other answerers a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the controls on your monitor so that the entire projected image is on the visible display.

Comment: Most monitors provide an 'auto' function to do this at the press of a button.